# The react-router-sitemap creates 2 sitemap files

Tags: reactjs, react-router, sitemap

router-sitemap creates 2 files, 
sitemap.xml which contains the url of the second xml www.domain.com/sitemap-0.xml

and sitemap-0.xml contains the paths
www.domain.com/
www.domain.com/path1 
etc etc

How can I configure react-router-sitemap in order to save only one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation is in line with the XML Sitemaps Protocol. The XML Sitemaps Protocol limits each XML sitemap file to maximum 50.000 urls. So, to accommodate more URLs, you can create a sitemap index file and link it to multiple sitemap files.

Source: https://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/help/xml-sitemaps-page-limit/

However, if you want to generate only one file, you'll have to make some changes in the source code. (There is no configuration available as of yet)

Go to lib/index.js and inside the save() function, add the following lines:

```
// sitemap index is not needed in case of one sitemap file
if (this.sitemaps.length === 1) {
    // write sitemap
    fs.writeFileSync(dist, this.sitemaps[0].toString());

    return this;
}
```